# Javafx window border manipulation not working

Tags: java, macos, user-interface, javafx, fxml

I am new to javafx and I am using FXML from Gluon's Scene Builder.

I am trying to get rounded corners on my application's window. I have tried doing it manually in my main class.

```
public class Main extends Application {
    private double x = 0;
    private double y = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("layout.fxml"));

        // Here is my attempt
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-radius: 10px;");

        root.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
                x = e.getSceneX();
                y = e.getSceneY();
        });

        root.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
                primaryStage.setX(e.getScreenX() - x);
                primaryStage.setY(e.getScreenY() - y);
        });

        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

I have also tried to achieve this in scene builder by inputting the same property above in the CSS field.

Comment: I've had a recent issue with javafx borders. In my case, there were a proprety in the default theme CSS that I should override. Maybe comments on this question help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46355643/get-rid-of-duplicated-border-on-javafx-scene-control-textfield?noredirect=1#comment79687539_46355643

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the Scene’s fill to null or Color.TRANSPARENT:

```
Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 300);
scene.setFill(null);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
```